# Construct new column with first row of a groupby with two columns - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to construct a new column that gives a value of 1 if it's the first time that an element of the column "type" has had a specific value of the column "xx", and  gives a value of 0 in any other case.

- The original dataframe (df) I am working with is:

  ```
  idx = [np.array(['Jan-18', 'Jan-18', 'Feb-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Apr-18', 'Apr-18', 'May-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18','Jul-18', 'Aug-18', 'Aug-18', 'Sep-18', 'Sep-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Oct-18', 'Nov-18', 'Dec-18', 'Dec-18',]),np.array(['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'])]
  data = [{'xx': 1000}, {'xx': 1000}, {'xx': 1200}, {'xx': 800}, {'xx': 800}, {'xx': 800},{'xx': 1000}, {'xx': 1000}, {'xx': 800}, {'xx': 1200}, {'xx': 1200}, {'xx': 1200},{'xx': 1000}, {'xx': 1000}, {'xx': 1000}, {'xx': 1600}, {'xx': 1600}, {'xx': 1000}, {'xx': 800}, {'xx': 800}, {'xx': 1000}, {'xx': 1600}, {'xx': 1600}]
  df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['xx'])
  df.index.names=['date','type']
  df=df.reset_index()
  df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format = '%b-%y')
  df=df.set_index(['date','type'])
  df['xx'] = df.xx.astype('float')
  ```
- The result I am looking for is:

  ```
                       xx   yy
  date       type
  2018-01-01 A     1000.0  1.0
             B     1000.0  1.0
  2018-02-01 B     1200.0  1.0
  2018-03-01 A      800.0  1.0
             B      800.0  1.0
             C      800.0  1.0
  2018-04-01 A     1000.0  0.0
             B     1000.0  0.0
  2018-05-01 B      800.0  0.0
  2018-06-01 A     1200.0  1.0
             B     1200.0  0.0
             C     1200.0  1.0
  2018-07-01 A     1000.0  0.0
  2018-08-01 B     1000.0  0.0
             C     1000.0  1.0
  2018-09-01 A     1600.0  1.0
             B     1600.0  1.0
  2018-10-01 C     1000.0  0.0
             A      800.0  0.0
             B      800.0  0.0
  2018-11-01 A     1000.0  0.0
  2018-12-01 B     1600.0  0.0
             C     1600.0  1.0
  ```
- I tried the following code, but it doesn't work (it gives an errror message):

  ```
  df['yy'] = df.assign(zz=(df.groupby(['type','xx']).first())).zz.transform(lambda x: 1)
  ```

The error message says

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1.

I tried other metodhos, such as nth(0), but it doesn't work either. Any suggestion of how solving this problem is very welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
df['yy'] = (df.groupby(level=1).xx
              .apply(lambda x: (~x.duplicated()).astype(int))
           )

df['yy']
```

outputs:

```
date        type
2018-01-01  A       1
            B       1
2018-02-01  B       1
2018-03-01  A       1
            B       1
            C       1
2018-04-01  A       0
            B       0
2018-05-01  B       0
2018-06-01  A       1
            B       0
            C       1
2018-07-01  A       0
2018-08-01  B       0
            C       1
2018-09-01  A       1
            B       1
2018-10-01  C       0
            A       0
            B       0
2018-11-01  A       0
2018-12-01  B       0
            C       1
Name: yy, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Great answer.. +1  did you know that you can use the index label name also?  instead of level=0.  I think it is more readable when you have index labels.  `df['yy'] = df.groupby('type')['xx'].apply(lambda x: (~x.duplicated()).astype(int))`

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks. Yes, as you mentioned, we can do `groupby('type')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang +1. Can you please explain what does the symbol ~ does in your solution. Thanks

Comment: @MarioArend that's negate operation, (True->False and False -> True).

Answer (score 5):

Using `groupby` + `cumcount` + `astype` :

```
df['yy'] = df.reset_index().groupby(['type','xx']).cumcount().eq(0).astype(int).values
```

Result:

```
                     xx  yy
date       type            
2018-01-01 A     1000.0   1
           B     1000.0   1
2018-02-01 B     1200.0   1
2018-03-01 A      800.0   1
           B      800.0   1
           C      800.0   1
2018-04-01 A     1000.0   0
           B     1000.0   0
2018-05-01 B      800.0   0
2018-06-01 A     1200.0   1
           B     1200.0   0
           C     1200.0   1
2018-07-01 A     1000.0   0
2018-08-01 B     1000.0   0
           C     1000.0   1
2018-09-01 A     1600.0   1
           B     1600.0   1
2018-10-01 C     1000.0   0
           A      800.0   0
           B      800.0   0
2018-11-01 A     1000.0   0
2018-12-01 B     1600.0   0
           C     1600.0   1
```

Comment: @piRSquared beat me to the punch, the 'values' was missing since the resulting series had a range index instead of the correct date intex

Comment: I never noticed this before and it smells wrong to me that `df.reset_index().groupby(['type','xx']).cumcount()` doesn't produce and index with `['type', 'xx']` as levels.  I edited to assign with the `values` attribute.

Comment: good point, as if the chaining sequence it's the other way around. Maybe someone could shed some light on this issue

Comment: However, given an appropriately high version of Pandas, you can include `index` level names in the `groupby`... so this works `df.groupby(['type', 'xx']).cumcount().eq(0)`

Comment: @piRSquared and Yuca: +1 very intuitive, good answer. Thanks for the explanation of using values, which  helped to solve the problem

Comment: @MarioArend exito Mario! un gusto poder ayudar

Comment: `df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(1),df.xx]).xx.cumcount().eq(0).astype(int)`

Answer (score 4):

#### `duplicated`

- Generate of list of tuples with `type` and `xx`
- Wrap it in a `pandas.Series` because I want to use the `pandas.Series.duplicated` method
- Use `numpy.where` to choose between `0` and `1`

**Note:** This does not use `groupby` and consequently should be more efficient.

---

```
s = pd.Series([*zip(df.index.get_level_values('type'), df.xx)])
df.assign(id=np.where(s.duplicated(), 0, 1))

                     xx  id
date       type            
2018-01-01 A     1000.0   1
           B     1000.0   1
2018-02-01 B     1200.0   1
2018-03-01 A      800.0   1
           B      800.0   1
           C      800.0   1
2018-04-01 A     1000.0   0
           B     1000.0   0
2018-05-01 B      800.0   0
2018-06-01 A     1200.0   1
           B     1200.0   0
           C     1200.0   1
2018-07-01 A     1000.0   0
2018-08-01 B     1000.0   0
           C     1000.0   1
2018-09-01 A     1600.0   1
           B     1600.0   1
2018-10-01 C     1000.0   0
           A      800.0   0
           B      800.0   0
2018-11-01 A     1000.0   0
2018-12-01 B     1600.0   0
           C     1600.0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
idx=df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(1),df.xx]).head(1).index
df.loc[:,'new']=0
df.loc[idx,'new']=1
df
Out[869]: 
                     xx  new
date       type             
2018-01-01 A     1000.0    1
           B     1000.0    1
2018-02-01 B     1200.0    1
2018-03-01 A      800.0    1
           B      800.0    1
           C      800.0    1
2018-04-01 A     1000.0    0
           B     1000.0    0
2018-05-01 B      800.0    0
2018-06-01 A     1200.0    1
           B     1200.0    0
           C     1200.0    1
2018-07-01 A     1000.0    0
2018-08-01 B     1000.0    0
           C     1000.0    1
2018-09-01 A     1600.0    1
           B     1600.0    1
2018-10-01 C     1000.0    0
           A      800.0    0
           B      800.0    0
2018-11-01 A     1000.0    0
2018-12-01 B     1600.0    0
           C     1600.0    1
```